Why is an application download larger post-download?
I downloaded Firefox and noticed it's larger after downloading. Can someone help me understand why?
Steps to reproduce:

Download Firefox from the website - it's 147 MB
Open the app, finish install
Check System Settings -> General -> Storage -> Applications, see it's 418 MB

Why is it larger now? I would expect it to be the same.

When you buy a tent in the store, it is packed in a small box.  But when you take it home and set it up, it becomes a lot larger.  I would imagine the same principle applies here.

More generally stated, installation packages are usually compressed. Once upon a time, the world was connected by 300 baud acoustic couplers. Compression could save hours downloading a file if it was over 1M.
